# Apache Ignite Spring Data 2.0 parse query exception

Tags: java, ignite

All queries from IgniteRepository works fine, but no one custom query like below doesn't work.

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "orders")
public interface OrderRepository extends IgniteRepository<Order, Long> {
    List<Order> findAllByClientId(Long clientId);
}
```

```
javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to parse query. Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT ""orders"".""ORDER""._KEY, ""orders"".""ORDER""._VAL FROM ORDER[*] WHERE ((ORDER.CLIENTID=?)) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
SELECT "orders"."ORDER"._KEY, "orders"."ORDER"._VAL FROM Order WHERE ((Order.clientId=?)) [42001-197]
```

Cache Config:

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableIgniteRepositories("repositories")
public class RepositoriesTestConfig {
    @Bean("igniteCfg")
    public IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration() {
        IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
        igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(false);
        igniteConfiguration.setIgniteInstanceName(instanceName);
        igniteConfiguration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

        CacheConfiguration<Long, Order> ordersCacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<>("orders");
        ordersCacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Order.class);
        igniteConfiguration.setCacheConfiguration(ordersCacheConfiguration);

        return igniteConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean("igniteInstance")
    public Ignite igniteInstance(@Autowired IgniteConfiguration 
    igniteConfiguration) {
        final Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration);
        return ignite;
    }
}
```

It seems that problem is not new. But impossible to find any solution. The same problem when use @Query annotation.

**UPDATE:**

The problem was with Order.class naming, Order1 - works, sql parses.